# Sign your Flutter app with upload key (App signing by Google Play)

Tags: android-studio, flutter, google-play-console

I have opted in to [App signing by Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en). How should I configure my Flutter app in Android Studio so that Google handles app signing? I could not find any documentation about it and for the moment I had to go with the [standard process](https://medium.com/@psyanite/how-to-sign-and-release-your-flutter-app-ed5e9531c2ac) by using a keystore.

Comment: Hey please follow below document : https://medium.com/@psyanite/how-to-sign-and-release-your-flutter-app-ed5e9531c2ac

Comment: this is not what I am asking. I have used the keystore and opted-in to app signing by google play. now Google play generated a certificate (upload key). I want to understand how to use this certificate to sign the app instead of the keystore.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I went to update an app this week and I can't determine if I was automatically opted in to this whereas I used to do the signing in the instructions the old way.  The solution below doesn't work for me because I don't have this option of "Generate Signed Bundle"

Comment: No.I have not figured out. I am still using standard way for signing the app using a key store.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue, heres the workaround i used:

- Go to Android Studio
- Open your project "android" folder
- Go to Build -> Generate Signed bundle or APK.
- Create your key store if you dont have
- Check "Export encrypted key for enrolling published apps in Google Play App signing" [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UA0Mw.png)
- Use the output bundle ;)

Comment: Just to clarify based on the ambiguity of 'opening' the android folder; You should open it as an Android Studio project, so File -> Open... -> your projects android folder.

Answer (score 3):

#### Step one (generate):

`keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload`

#### Step two (export):

`keytool -export -rfc -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem`

#### Step three (setup on google play console):

You have the files, now you need only to upload them to google.

Answer (score 2):

The singing process works as described by the flutter documentation [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#signing-the-app). Regardless of whether you are using *Play App Signing* or not.

When opting into *Play App Signing* the app is being signed twice. Once by the developer with an *upload key* and once by Google with the *app signing key*. The advantage here is that it won't come to the point where the developer can no longer update their app because they lost the *app signing key*. Should you loose the *upload key*, it can be revoked and replaced using your Google account while still being able to release new versions of your app as the *app signing key* is still held securely by Google.

[This android developer article](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#app-signing-google-play) explains in more detail how *Play App Signing* works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and this is what worked for me: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#enroll

> As described earlier in this page, Play App Signing is the recommended
> way to sign your app for distribution through Google Play. The steps
> you need to take in order to opt in your app depends on whether your
> app has not yet been published to Google Play, or your app is already
> signed and published using an existing app signing key.
>
> To opt in an app that has not yet been published to
> Google Play, proceed as follows:
>
> 1. If you haven’t already done so, [generate an upload key](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key) and [sign your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign_release) with that upload key.
> 2. Sign in to your Play Console.
> 3. Follow the steps to prepare & roll out your release to create a new release.
> 4. After you choose a release track, configure app signing under the Let
>    Google create and manage my app signing key section